# populating textboxes with less than / greater than symbols (< and >)

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

so I've been running into some problems where in various parts of my website I'm developing, I'm displaying some logs that contain < and > symbols in various spots. Well when I display the log it works fine. Of course anytime I navigate away I get an error of:

A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client ...

Now I understand it's because < and > are html special characters which I get. But, is there any way to disable or somehow allow the page to display / process those? I know I could strip those characters out of anyplace they may appear, but I'd rather not if I don't have to.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: .net 4.0 on an IIS 7.5 server. Visual studio 2010.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# / ASP.net " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Answer (score 5):

You didn't post any code, so I will assume you want something along the lines of:

```
<textbox><</textbox>
```

It's simple really, HTML encode your content:

```
<textbox>&lt;</textbox>
```

You can use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Replace "**>**" with "**&gt;**" and "**<**" with "**&lt;**"

Read [this](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/special.html) see a list of HTMLs special entities

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want your web application to allow form input to contain potentially dangerous characters there are a few ways to do this depending on framework. I mostly use MVC myself, where you use the `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute on your controller actions.

For WebForms, I'll direct you here instead.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bt244wbb.aspx :)

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question put `ValidateRequest="false"`  in `<%@Page`...

be careful, as you are now responsible for prevent script attacks

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error and solved it simply by setting the property "Enabled" of the textboxes on "false". Guess this prevents the value of the textboxes being validated.

Displaying the texts in labels instead of textboxes also works.